# Tensorflow Object Detection API, tutorial with differing results

Tags: python, matplotlib, tensorflow

I followed the steps suggested into [installation section](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/g3doc/installation.md), and I executed the [suggested example](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/object_detection_tutorial.ipynb). The surprise was the different values obtained If we compare the solution showed into the presentation page. I would like to explore if this behavior is correct or is an error of my implementation.

I'm using tensorflow 1.2.1
I followed these [instructions](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/g3doc/installation.md), and I tested the installation using the suggested tests:

[image: test executed]

I'm using MacOs SO, and I using these lib version into my environment: pillow 4.2.0, protobuf 3.3.0, matplotlib 2.0.2, lxml 3.8.0.

This is the result after the execution:
result 1
[image]
result 2
[image]
But this result is quite different that the examples showed into the presentation, the accuracy is different:
[image]

Comment: i think the accuracy has something to do with image resolution

Comment: @Idle001 I used the same images proposed into the example. models/object_detection/test_images/.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are using `ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_11_06_2017` model for testing the results. Try using other models:

```
MODEL_NAME = 'ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_11_06_2017'

MODEL_NAME = 'ssd_inception_v2_coco_11_06_2017'

MODEL_NAME = 'rfcn_resnet101_coco_11_06_2017' 

MODEL_NAME = 'faster_rcnn_resnet101_coco_11_06_2017'

MODEL_NAME = 'faster_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2_atrous_coco_11_06_2017'
```

`faster_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2_atrous_coco_11_06_2017` will give you the same result as shown in tutorial.